# Place Data from Same Column in Different Columns in Resultset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a request I wasn't sure to handle. I was thinking of using PIVOT, but I wasn't sure if that would be the way to go.

I have the following Data:

```
EmployeeA, DepartmentB, 1/10/2010
EmployeeA, DepartmentA, 1/1/2000
EmployeeB, DepartmentC, 1/3/2011
```

They want output for only the employees that have been in different departments. Something that looks like this (order is important due to the dates):

```
EmployeeA, DepartmentA, DepartmentB
```

Any help is appreciated. For some reason, my mind isn't finding a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by doing a self `JOIN` on the table and then using a `PIVOT` to get the data in the format that you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT t1.emp, t1.dept, t1.dt
    FROM  test t1
    INNER JOIN test t2
        ON t1.emp = t2.emp
        AND t1.dept != t2.dept
) x
PIVOT
(
    min(dt)
    for dept in ([A], [B], [C], [D], [E])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9dca31/1)

If you remove the `JOIN` you will get all records, but you stated you only want the records that have been in more than one department.

Comment: Works great. Only one issue. There can only be two "department" columns. Previous and current.

Comment: @geoffrobinson I am not sure what you mean only two departments.

Comment: I got the answer largely from your help. I'll post in a second.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer I got which I got largely based on your work. Pivot doesn't work because I don't know the categories (in this case Department) ahead of time and I can only have two of them.

Maybe there's an easier way. I didn't use a CTE, because I believe this should work for Sybase as well which I don't think supports that.

```
   select Meta1.[Employee ID], 
Meta1.Department as PreviousDepartment,
Meta2.Department as CurrentDepartment
from
(
SELECT t1.[First Name], t1.[Last Name],
t1.[Employee ID], t1.Department, t1.[Hire Date],
ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by t1.[EMPLOYEE ID] order by t1.[Hire Date]) as RowNum
FROM  EMPLOYEE t1
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE t2
    ON t1.[Employee ID] = t2.[Employee ID]
    AND t1.Department != t2.Department
) Meta1  
inner join
(
SELECT t1.[Employee ID], t1.Department, t1.[Hire Date],
ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by t1.[EMPLOYEE ID] order by t1.[Hire Date]) as RowNum
FROM  EMPLOYEE t1
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE t2
    ON t1.[Employee ID] = t2.[Employee ID]
    AND t1.Department != t2.Department
) Meta2
on Meta1.[Employee ID]=Meta2.[Employee ID]
where Meta1.RowNum=1
and Meta2.RowNum=2
```

Comment: If you don't know the departments beforehand, a `PIVOT` can still work.  There is a dynamic pivot that can be written see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query/10404455#10404455)